# MERN API GET requests return 404's on Heroku, works on local Raspi server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have a MERN application that I'm trying to host on Heroku. Right now the application is deployed to a Raspberry Pi, and everything works fine there, but as soon as it gets to Heroku all of my API GET requests result in 404 errors. I can get the React front end, but nothing else works. The Mongo portion is hosted on the sandbox tier of Atlas and is whitelisted to accept any authorized connections.

Things that I've tried:

- [Not routing /api calls to static React files via server.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266865/mern-app-deployed-to-heroku-not-working-properly)
- Updating all references to port numbers to use `process.env.PORT || 3001`
- Swapping my proxy in my React client package.json from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`
- Reconfiguring my axios calls to the API with the following config:

```
const axiosConfig = {
  proxy:{
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3001
  }
};
```

GET requests in my API result in 404's on Heroku with the following error message: `xhr.js:173 GET https://builders-kit-0031.herokuapp.com/api/humidity 404 (Not Found)`.

I'm authenticating to Atlas with a keys file:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
  module.exports = require('./keys_prod');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./keys_dev');
}
```

That file pulls in the following file, which uses the MONGO_URI and SECRET_OR_KEY string that I set in the config vars section of Heroku.

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY
};
```

My code is set up to serve React via the Express server (all react stuff in a `/client` folder). I'm currently deploying with a Heroku postbuild script like so: `"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true NODE_ENV=production npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"`.

I think that's all of the big hotspots that I've found since researching this on here this morning. Any and all advice about things to try would be greatly appreciated. You can check out the broken version of what I'm trying to deploy [here](https://builders-kit-0031.herokuapp.com/). Happy to post any other snippets of code if that would help debugging - didn't want to post the entire application. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome. We cannot debug your full application and/or deployment here. Before posting it is generally expected you have taken "basic steps" in **reproducing** the problem with a **minimal listing**. Those are the basic points from the standard message as posted above. Make a small program and deployment and keep adding things until you see the same problem you see now in your application. Then you know what to ask/"look for".

Comment: Hey @NeilLunn - apologies, I thought that my description was clear enough here. The exact issue that I'm having is that any and all GET requests to my API are failing when deployed to Heroku, but they all work with the Atlas-hosted database when running from local. I have a similar bare-bones application that just authenticates users against an Mongodb cluster on Atlas that is deployed on heroku, and it's hitting the same issue. Most of the information I'm finding online is tailored for mLab rather than Atlas - I'm wondering if there isn't a step that I'm missing for making that transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured out what was going on here. This appears to be related to how the baseURL is set up in Axios.

During local development I made the mistake of assigning an IP variable and then making any API calls like so: `${ip}/api/whatever/whatever`

I thought I was on the right track with the Axios config I posted above, but what I actually needed to do was set up Axios like this:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'
});
```

I switched all of my API calls to refer to that `axiosInstance` rather than just `axios`, and then updated them all to use relative URLs. All of the API calls and DB connections are working as expected on staging now. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Also found one other issue that was messing up a few API calls - I didn't have my .env ignored because I wasn't storing any sensitive data in it, and I thought it was getting pushed up to heroku, but it seems like it wasn't. Redefined all the variables in Heroku env vars and those parts work now.